# Why am I not allowed to downvote my own post?

Tags: feature-request, support

It's alright that users aren't allowed to upvote their own posts. But, what about downvote?

Users can mis-use upvote, but users can't mis-use downvote.

Add this feature.. With it, a user can downvote his question/answer at later point of time when he finds that it's poor. Today, I was trying to do that, but failed.

Comment: Ehm, if your answer is poor, improve or remove it?

Comment: That's just.. silly. No offense meant. Like Bart said, if you think your own answer is poor, improve it. If it's beyond fixing, delete it. What you suggest is like the option to give yourself a loan in the bank or something like that.

Comment: dont worry we can do it for you:P

Comment: Voting is not some arbitrary thing. It's *supposed* to influence your reputation. You should not have influence over your own reputation.

Comment: @meagar I know that. Think how great I am..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a link, I'll downvote it for you if you like.

Seriously, couldn't you just improve the post, or delete it if it's so bad? The votes are a signal to the poster that something is wrong with their post. Why would you need to send that signal to yourself?

Answer (score 17):

> but users can't mis-use downvote.

I'd abuse the hell out of this:

1. Post a good question/answer,
2. Immediately down vote it,
3. Post a comment complaining that people down voted me without explaining,
4. Profit! (gather the sweet sympathy votes)

Comment: You surely have a creative mind! :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I've seen so many "+1 to counteract the unjustified -1" comments that I'm absolutely certain this would work.

Comment: I would never give such vote but guess you have a point.. :/

Comment: Nice, but I already have a sock puppet for that.

Comment: If community is ok, sympathy shouldn't work.

Comment: I doubt that StackExchange has much sympathy here.